# How to find out if an array already contains a value and if it does skip to the next value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently I have a function that updates some ui(movie categories). It gets the ui data from json and updates the image based on the url string the json gives.  The json data that comes back is in an array so what I'm currently doing is taking the first element in that array and using that for the ui.  The only problem is I've noticed the first json data in the array is using the same image string for multiple categories.

What I'm trying to do is check to see if the array contains the current string, if it does skip to the next one until it reaches a string not in the array.  When it reaches this string append it to the array. Here's what I have so far -

This is the function I use to update the retrieved json info:

```
 static func updateGenrePoster(genreID: NSNumber, urlExtension: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ details: [String]) -> Void){

    var posterArray: [String] = []

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

    nm.getJSONData(type:"genre/\(genreID)", urlExtension: urlExtension, completion: {
      data in

      if let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONData(data)
      {
        guard let genrePoster = ResultsGenrePosters(json: jsonDictionary)

          else {
            print("Error initializing object")
            return
        }
        guard let posterString = genrePoster.results?[0].poster//This is where I want to check to see if array already contains the string

          else {
            print("No such item")
            return
        }
        posterArray.append(posterString)

      }
      completionHandler(posterArray)
    })
  }
```

This is the function I use to update the ui:

```
 func updateUI()// updates Tableview IBOutlets
  {
    if let genreID = genreData.id {

      GenrePosters.updateGenrePoster(genreID: genreID, urlExtension: "movies", completionHandler: {posters in

       for poster in posters{

          self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(poster)",

            { (imageData) //imageData = Image data downloaded from web
              in
              let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

              DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { //Must update UI on main thread so have to get main queue
                self.genreCatagoryLabel.text = self.genreData.name
                self.mainImageView.image = image
              })
          })
        }

      })
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do it there? If you're in a loop all you have to say is something like `if posterArray.contains(item) { do something } else { continue }`

Comment: That's along the path I'm going, but how can I have it jump to the next item if the array already contains the value?

Comment: That's what `continue` is for

Comment: If you're inside a loop, `continue` will take you to the next iteration without breaking the loop

Comment: I didn't know that, learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to use a Set.  As you're going through your array, just do something like this (approx code, I didn't try for syntax):

```
if mySet.Contains(the_current_string)
{
    // skip this one since it's a dupe
    continue
}
else
{
    mySet.Append(the_current_string)
}
```

Edit: I've taken the liberty of spelling it out since my original post seems to have been ambiguous.

```
func pointlessMethod()
{
    let arrayOfStrings = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"]
    var mySet: Set<String> = []
    for someString in arrayOfStrings
    {
        if mySet.contains(someString)
        {
            continue
        }
        else
        {
            mySet.insert(someString)
        }

        // Do the stuff you want to do with the non-dupe
    }
}
```

Comment: Set by definition only contains unique items, so there is no real need to check if it exists or not before appending.

Comment: You check so you know to skip it.  I suppose the else is redundant, but many "style guides" ask that every "if" has an "else".  The "continue", in the scope of the loop, tells it to "forget the stuff below and just continue to the next item for the loop clause".

Comment: And beware that sets are unordered, so the order of the original array would be lost.

Comment: Yes, I meant as a companion to the array that's being enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're trying to do is to get all distinct strings in the array to only load each image once.

You can do that in swift in few ways:

1. Use a `Set` instead of an array initially, and only in the end return an array created from the set:

   let posterArray = Array(posterSet)
   completion(posterArray)
2. Keep an array, and in the end clear duplicates (via converting to set and back for example, or there are other ways like contains-append)

Using sets  will make you loose the ordering though.

From the code you posted, it seems that posters array will always have one item. Did I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Using a set would work, but the order of the items would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that would take an array of String objects and return a result array containing the first unique elements from the source array of Strings:

```
func uniqueElementsFrom(array: [String]) -> [String] {
  var set = Set<String>()
  let result = array.filter {
    guard !set.contains($0) else {
      return false
    }
    set.insert($0)
    return true
  }
  return result
  }

let arrayOfStrings = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"]
let uniqueStrings = uniqueElementsFrom(array:arrayOfStrings)
print("Unique elements from \(arrayOfStrings) = \n  \(uniqueStrings)")
```

That code uses a `Set` to keep track of the unique elements in the array. It uses the Swift `filter` function, which is a function that takes a closure. (The code in curly braces after the filter command.) The closure takes an element from the array as it's only parameter, and returns `true` if the element should be included in the resulting array, or `false` if it should be skipped.

That function yields the output:

> Unique elements from ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"] = 
>      ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Better yet, you could rewrite the `uniqueElementsFrom(array:)` function to take an array of any element that conforms to the Hashable protocol. To do that, you use Generics.

Below is the `uniqueElementsFrom(array:)` function rewritten to work on any array of objects where the objects are `Hashable`

```
func uniqueElementsFrom<T: Hashable>(array: [T]) -> [T] {
  var set = Set<T>()
  let result = array.filter {
    guard !set.contains($0) else {
      return false
    }
    set.insert($0)
    return true
  }
  return result
}
```

The `<T: Hashable>` bit after the function name says "The rest of this function will refer to a type T which is unspecified. The only thing you can be sure of is that the type T will conform to the `Hashable` protocol."

So if you pass in an array of `String`s, all mentions of `T` in the header and function body get replaced with `String`

The new version of the function gives exactly the same output as the previous version, but you can pass it an array containing any kind of objects as long as that type is `Hashable`.

So you could just as easily use the function like this:

```
let intArray = [1, 3, 17, 9, 1, 17, 3, 4]
let uniqueArray = uniqueElementsFrom(array:intArray)
print("Unique elements from \(intArray) = \n  \(uniqueArray)")
```

And you'd get the output

> Unique elements from [1, 3, 17, 9, 1, 17, 3, 4] = 
>     [1, 3, 17, 9, 4]